# Matplotlib using wide right margin - Python

Tags: python, layout, matplotlib, plot, margin

I'm plotting a data with lots of information and I would like to use the whole area of the plot. However, even using `tight_layout`, I end up with a "wide" right margin. For example:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cmap = plt.get_cmap('Set3')
colors = [cmap(i) for i in numpy.linspace(0, 1, 18)]

data = numpy.random.rand(18, 365)

y = range(365)
plt.figure(figsize=(15,7))
for i in range(18):
    plt.plot(y, data[i, :], color=colors[i], linewidth=2)
plt.xticks(numpy.arange(0, 365, 10))
plt.tight_layout()
```

Produces something like:

[image]

I'd like to know how to get rid of this right margin, so the `xtikcs` used are could expand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cut the right margin of by setting `xlim`. In your code add `plt.xlim(0, 364)` after you set the `xticks`. You can determine whatever section along the x-axis is plotted based on the two values you supply. When using actual data it is better to use the `min` and `max` values of your `x array`. In the example you supplied this means: `plt.xlim(min(y), max(y))`.

Comment: Perfect! I don't know how I forgot about this property!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in the following way:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cmap = plt.get_cmap('Set3')
colors = [cmap(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, 18)]

data = np.random.rand(18, 365)

y = range(365)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
for i in range(18):
    ax.plot(y, data[i, :], color=colors[i], linewidth=2)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 365, 10))
ax.set_xlim(ax.xaxis.get_data_interval())
fig.tight_layout()
```

It is slightly more pythonic.